# Creating model migration & resource controller but controller in different folder with model param

Tags: laravel

i am using this

```
php artisan make:model Category -mcr`
```

Its fine but i want this resource controller
with model parameter in different folder.
Thank you for help/suggestions.

Comment: What have you tried or search for so far?

Comment: after creating with above command i only move the controller file to the folder and then change namespace and controller extends to the class.
like this:

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Folder;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;